# Image within SwiftUI TabView not resizing correctly

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm trying to create a TabView of images that is sized to fit a WaterfallGrid parent view. However, I'm not seeing a way to do this. I can force the frame size of the TabView but I'm looking to have it resize to some sensible size within the WaterfallGrid that fits the set of images it has.

I attached a screenshot with the WaterfallView showing two posts with a single image (sized to fit correctly), and a multi-image TabView that isn't resizing as expected.

Here is my WaterfallGrid cell view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PostCellView: View {
  var post: Post
  
  var body: some View {
    switch post.type {
    case .photo:
      if !post.images.isEmpty {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          if post.images.count == 1, let image = UIImage(data: post.images[0]) {
            Image(uiImage: image)
              .resizable()
              .scaledToFit()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              .clipped()
              .cornerRadius(12)
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
              .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                  .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                  .opacity(0.4)
              )
          } else {
            TabView {
              ForEach(post.images, id: \.self) { imageData in
                if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                  Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipped()
                }
              }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .overlay(
              RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                .opacity(0.4)
            )
          }
          
          if post.caption != "" {
            Text(post.caption)
              .font(.subheadline)
              .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 4, bottom: 2, trailing: 4))
          }
          DateTextView(post: post)
        }
      }
    case .text:
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(post.caption)
          .font(.title3)
          .fontWeight(.medium)
          .padding(22)
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
          .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
              .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
              .opacity(0.7)
          )
        DateTextView(post: post)
       }
    }
  }
  
  struct DateTextView: View {
    var post: Post
    
    var body: some View {
      Text(post.date.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
        .font(.system(size: 12).weight(.light))
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 4, bottom: 0, trailing: 4))
        .monospaced()
    }
  }
}
```

And the parent view that creates the WaterfallView:

```
import SwiftUI
import WaterfallGrid

struct PostGridView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model: PostGridViewModel
  @State private var showingCreatePostPopover = false
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
      WaterfallGrid(model.posts) { post in
        PostCellView(post: post)
          .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
          .contextMenu {
            Button {
              model.delete(post: post)
            } label: {
              Text("Delete")
            }
          }
      }
      .gridStyle(
        columnsInPortrait: 2,
        columnsInLandscape: 3,
        spacing: 8
      )
      .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 8, bottom: 16, trailing: 8))
    }
    .navigationTitle(model.passion.title)
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button("", systemImage: "plus") {
          showingCreatePostPopover = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingCreatePostPopover) {
          CreatePostPopoverView(model: model)
        }
      }
    }
    .onDisappear {
      model.save()
    }
  }
}
```

[image]